# How to find tenure in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to calculate employee tenure in a company in SQL Server like I find it in Excel:

[image]

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 17.

Comment: @SajjadGul . . . This is quite hard to do in the database.  If you *really* need this format, then you should probably write a function in the database to do it.  Otherwise, stick with decimal years or months.

Answer (score 0):

I have come to that solution and it meets my requirements.[Click to see Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONmWU.png)